# Azure Functions Node.js V4: Where is `context.executionContext.functionDirectory` to load external files?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

In Azure Functions Node.js V3 there's a property `context.executionContext.functionDirectory`

Also see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function#javascriptnodejs

I want to load an external file but with V4 the property is missing.

**How do I know the function's directory in V4?**

In V4 I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'functionDirectory')
```

... which means that `context.executionContext` does not exist. This is how it looks like when I simply do `context.log(context)`:

```json
InvocationContext {
    invocationId: '46bf4cfd-614b-4363-84f9-e5e3915393ab',
    functionName: 'blah',
    extraInputs: InvocationContextExtraInputs {},
    extraOutputs: InvocationContextExtraOutputs {},
    retryContext: undefined,
    traceContext: {
        traceParent: '00-87e8919a8bf45cb09255ee0281d6e30c-98f0309ae154a6ba-00',
        traceState: '',
        attributes: {}
    },
    triggerMetadata: undefined,
    options: {
        trigger: {
            methods: [Array],
            authLevel: 'anonymous',
            route: 'blah/{**path}',
            type: 'httpTrigger',
            name: 'httpTrigger1',
            direction: 'in'
        },
        return : {
            type: 'http',
            name: '$return',
            direction: 'out'
        },
        extraInputs: [],
        extraOutputs: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried and found it: in Node.js V4 model you can simply call `const fileData = await fs.readFile('./helloWorld.txt');` as [shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#use-async-and-await) **and you don't need to care about the function directory anymore** because you can navigate using a relative path to your function and don't need to specify the absolute path.

Example: The default structure is as follows (Visual Studio Code):

```
[.vscode]
[src]
    [functions]
        myHttpTrigger.js
host.json
local.settings.json
package.json
```

I added `resources` under the `src` directory and copied an image in there:

```
[.vscode]
[src]
    [functions]
        myHttpTrigger.js
    [resources]
        image.jpg
host.json
local.settings.json
package.json
```

And in my code I can read the file as follows:

```js
const { app } = require("@azure/functions");
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');

app.http('myHttpTrigger', {
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    let data = await fs.readFile('./src/resources/image.jpg', { encoding: null }); // null means binary, otherwise use something like 'utf8' to decode the file content
    data = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'); // encode binary content to base64 string
    return { body: data };
  }
});
```